# Как при нажатии на отдельный элемент RecyclerView перейти на другой активити?

Tags: java, recyclerview

Я пытаюсь написать фитнес приложение для просмотра упражнений на группы мышц, но не могу реализовать, чтобы при нажатии на отдельный элемент в списке RecyclerView переходило на новое активити с другим списком (упражнениями), и так с каждым элементом в списке со своим переходом в другой активити. Порыл весь интернет, не смог найти. Прошу помочь. Заранее спасибо.

MainActivity.java

```java
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerview;

    String muscul[];
    int images[] = {R.drawable.biceps, R.drawable.chest, R.drawable.calf, R.drawable.legs, R.drawable.shoulders, R.drawable.press, R.drawable.back, R.drawable.triceps};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        recyclerview = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

        muscul = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.MuscleGroups);


        recyclerview.setAdapter(new MyAdapter1(this, muscul, images));
        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
}
```

MyAdapter1.java

```java
    public class MyAdapter1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter1.MyViewHolder> {



    String data1[];
    int images[];
    Context context;

    public MyAdapter1(Context ct, String muscul[], int img[]) {
        context = ct;
        data1 = muscul;
        images = img;

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.musculs.setText(data1[position]);
        holder.musculImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView musculs;
        ImageView musculImage;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            musculs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.musculs);
            musculImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.musculImage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `holder.musculImage.setOnClickListener(v ->  holder.musculImage.getContext().startActivity(holder.musculImage.getContext(), ACTIVITY_TO_LAUNCH_CLASS_NAME_HERE.class));`?

Comment: Не сработало...

Comment: Невозможно вам помочь, если вы не даёте деталей. Мой код - сработает, при соблюдении ряда условий